# using qsort to sort an array of long long int not working for large nos

Tags: c, qsort

I am using this compare function to sort an array consisting of long long int nos.

```
int compare(const void * p1,const void * p2)
{
    return (* (long long int * )a-*(long long int * )b);
}
qsort(array,no of elements,sizeof(long long int),compare)
```

this works fine for small nos but when the array contains nos of the oreder of 10^10 it gives wrong results?

what is the mistake i am making?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The result of `compare` function must be `int`. The subtraction of two `long long` can easily overflow the `int` type (and it does in your case).

Try comparing the two values explicitly and returning -1, 0 or 1.

Answer (score 7):

explicitly return -1,1 or 0. This is the following code :

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    if( *(long long int*)a - *(long long int*)b < 0 )
        return -1;
    if( *(long long int*)a - *(long long int*)b > 0 )
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/